# Warn user before navigating to a different view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to warn user and get a confirmation before the user navigates away from certain pages in my application, like composing a new message view. Which events can i capture and cancel/continue to make this happen ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have say a link or button navigating to another route or state, you could simply show a modal confirming the navigation:

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToAnotherState()">Go Away...</a>

$scope.goToAnotherState = function(){

//show modal and get confirmating however your like
  if(modalResponse.Ok){
     $state.go('anotherState');
  }
}
```

another option would be to do this in the `$locationChangeStart` event of ui-router, but if you're looking to this only here n there, then the first approach is better. `$locationChangeStart` approach:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, prev) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //show modal
  if(modalResponse.ok){
    var destination = next.substr(next.indexOf('#') + 1, next.length).trim();
    $location.path(destination)
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to add `timeout` as location.path was not working. Also i had to add flag as on `location.path` it was calling same again so infinnite loop

Answer (score 8):

You should handle the $locationChangeStart event in order to hook up to view transition event, so use this code to handle the transition validation in your controller/s:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")
  if (!answer) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

also you can use this directive [angularjs-unsaved-changes](https://github.com/facultymatt/angular-unsavedChanges) which would be much more reusable than writing it per controller..

Comment: Thanks, but this event is raised in $rootScope, not in controller scope. does that mean i have to unsubscribe to this event in controllers '$destroy' event ? I don't want this event to be raised for every view. just a couple of them.

Comment: event is raised in $rootScope, but you can listen to it in any child scope and all the controller $scope are child of $rootScope, hence you can listen to this event only in controllers where you want to

Answer (score 0):

When defining a state, use the `onExit` callback, [which is a transition hook](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#onenteronexit-return-value):

> An onEnter/onExit declared on a state is processed as a standard Transition Hook. The return value of a hook may alter a transition.

```
.state('foo', {
  //dont return a value else it the transition will wait on the result to resolve (Promise)
  onEnter: (MyService) => { MyService.doThing(); },

  //return false to cancel the transition; i.e. prevent user from leaving
  onExit: (MyService) => { return MyService.isSatisfied(); }
});
```

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#onexit